# Error while entering the login form details based on signup form

Tags: django

I am trying to enter the details in login form.But it is not authenticating the username and password with the existing usernames and passwords present in form data.
Here is my code

```
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from . forms import signup_form,loginform,profileform
from . models import registration_form

def index(request):
    return render(request,'loginapp/index.html')

def display_form(request):
    rform = signup_form(request.POST)
    if rform.is_valid():
       rform.save()
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
       else:
          return render(request,'loginapp/first.html',{'rform': rform})

def login_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       Username = request.POST.get('Username')
       Password = request.POST.get('Password')
       registration_form=
            authenticate(Username=Username,Password=Password)
       print("Username")
       if registration_form is None:
          if registration_form.is_active:
            login(request,registration_form)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
          else:
            return HttpResponse("Your account was inactive.")
       else:
         print("Someone tried to login and failed.")
         print("They used Username: {} and Password: 
                              {}".format(Username,Password))
         return HttpResponse("Invalid login details given")
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    else:
      return render(request, 'loginapp/login.html', {})

def profile_form(request):
      return render(request,'loginapp/profile.html')
```

Comment: Your `registration_form` is in fact a `User`, it might be better to use proper nomenclature. It is possible to use a bit more indentation as well. The current indentation makes it hard to understnad the code flow.

Comment: Following what Willem said: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is the de facto style used by the vast majority of Python developers, following it helps people to read your code and would help you to read others as the style would be familiar. Class names (forms and models) are usually CapWords/CamelCase and variables and function names are usually lower_case_with_underscores